# Is there a Self-Imposed Bulk Operations Limit?

Tags: views

My database has millions of nodes.  We've been approved to delete a very large amount of them given certain criteria so I set up a view with VBO to handle the batch deletions.  I've exposed the pager limit setting in Views so I can run batches of different sizes.  When I try to run anything higher than 1000 nodes per batch (10 per run to prevent timeouts), the batch sets its max value to some number around 1000, depending on the server.  This is limiting me to run either 1000 at a time or attempt to run the entire result set.

I'm looking for any ideas as to why there is this seemingly self imposed limit on the bulk operations.  My sandbox server sets the batch max at 1001 while my production server sets it to 995.

- Drupal 7.27
- Views 3.7
- VBO 3.1

Answer (score 0):

No. there is no such limit.

In Views, make sure you have enabled the option to select all items across all pages. With that configuration, all items will be selected regardless of the pager configuration.

Comment: I have that option available.  It is currently the only way to process more than 1000 items at a time.  My issue is that I want to process 5,000 to 10,000 at a time, but I have no way to do that.  If I set the view limit to 20, it process 20, 100 loads 100, 1000 loads 995, 2000 loads 995, 5000 loads 995.  I want to know why it won't process more than 995 unless I select the entire view result, which could be 600,000.